# is there a way to discard all mail sent to a user

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis

I started to get some spam mails to a unique user, and that user does not exist in our system.

so I want that all mail for that nonexistent user gets discard.

is this possible?

**[update]**

my scenario is like this:

- we have a few defined users.
- we have a unique account to get all mail that get all mail (for undefined accounts), D_PASS and luser_relay.
- spamassassin usually score and discard the mail marked as spam.
- we started to receive some spam and their score like not spam, but is only to one
  unique (nonexistent) account.
- I want to discard all mail to that user, I don't care about the
  score.

Comment: Is it not already bouncing since the user doesn't exist?

Comment: no, because I have the general rule D_PASS all mail to a defined account, but in this special case, the mail scores like not spam (amavis).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `luser_relay`, in this way, you setup an email address for emails users that doesn't exist in your system

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay

Comment: I updated my question.